# How to read ARFF file in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following in ARFF format.

```
    @relation DT_mat
    @attribute V1 numeric
    @attribute V2 numeric
    @attribute V3 numeric
    @attribute V4 numeric
    ...
    @attribute V118 numeric
    @attribute V119 numeric
    @attribute V120 numeric
    @data
    233.06,799.33,0.0,-2.36,14.31,0.0,0.06,-0.37,0.0,-0.07,1.0,0.0,230.79,813.62,0.0,-2.36,14.36,0.0,-0.1,0.58,0.0,-0.07,1.0,0.0,228.36,827.93,0.0,-2.28,14.3,0.0,0.12,-0.75,0.0,-0.07,1.0,0.0,226.15,842.24,0.0,-2.25,14.3,0.0,0.08,-0.51,0.0,-0.08,1.0,0.0,224.15,856.55,0.0,-2.18,14.13,0.0,0.23,-1.47,0.0,-0.07,1.0,0.0,222.25,868.77,0.0,-1.65,10.68,0.0,0.56,-3.61,0.0,-0.07,1.0,0.0,220.95,877.76,0.0,-1.18,7.64,0.0,0.42,-2.7,0.0,-0.08,1.0,0.0,219.95,883.87,0.0,-0.76,4.92,0.0,0.39,-2.55,0.0,-0.08,1.0,0.0,219.19,887.9,0.0,-0.64,4.15,0.0,-0.4,2.57,0.0,-0.08,1.0,0.0,218.15,893.32,0.0,-1.4,6.36,0.0,-0.47,2.12,0.0,-0.14,0.99,0.0
151.24,924.73,0.0,0.11,-1.36,0.0,0.11,-1.35,0.0,0.08,-1.0,0.0,134.37,1100.75,0.0,0.76,-8.14,0.0,0.18,-1.93,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0,152.96,901.29,0.0,0.25,-2.55,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0,150.02,901.26,0.0,0.24,-2.54,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.1,-0.99,0.0,152.28,910.09,0.0,0.24,-2.55,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0,148.94,910.01,0.0,0.25,-2.55,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0,151.42,918.71,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0,132.2,1091.09,0.0,0.94,-10.04,0.0,0.14,-1.47,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0,153.61,893.54,0.0,0.16,-1.61,0.0,0.16,-1.62,0.0,0.09,-1.0,0.0,150.53,893.4,0.0,0.16,-1.62,0.0,0.16,-1.62,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0
152.66,904.56,0.0,0.06,-0.75,0.0,0.18,-2.43,0.0,0.07,-1.0,0.0,152.98,902.59,0.0,0.22,-2.91,0.0,0.12,-1.68,0.0,0.07,-1.0,0.0,153.25,898.68,0.0,0.37,-4.65,0.0,0.11,-1.35,0.0,0.08,-1.0,0.0,153.82,893.0,0.0,0.65,-6.67,0.0,0.25,-2.54,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0,154.46,885.22,0.0,0.85,-8.68,0.0,0.16,-1.62,0.0,0.1,-1.0,0.0,155.95,875.45,0.0,1.3,-10.76,0.0,0.26,-2.18,0.0,0.12,-0.99,0.0,157.47,863.69,0.0,1.56,-12.66,0.0,0.22,-1.83,0.0,0.12,-0.99,0.0,159.12,850.74,0.0,1.6,-12.97,0.0,0.01,-0.09,0.0,0.12,-0.99,0.0,160.79,837.77,0.0,1.69,-12.96,0.0,-0.02,0.18,0.0,0.13,-0.99,0.0,162.53,824.82,0.0,1.68,-12.91,0.0,-0.13,1.01,0.0,0.13,-0.99,0.0
111.59,891.42,0.0,0.27,0.02,0.0,2.67,0.23,0.0,1.0,0.08,0.0,113.44,891.56,0.0,2.74,0.23,0.0,2.42,0.21,0.0,1.0,0.08,0.0,117.15,891.8,0.0,4.54,0.31,0.0,2.2,0.15,0.0,1.0,0.06,0.0,122.87,892.12,0.0,5.63,0.32,0.0,-1.57,-0.09,0.0,1.0,0.04,0.0,127.24,892.36,0.0,3.3,0.19,0.0,-1.52,-0.09,0.0,1.0,0.04,0.0,129.69,892.49,0.0,1.67,0.1,0.0,-1.54,-0.09,0.0,1.0,0.04,0.0,130.79,892.55,0.0,0.71,0.04,0.0,-0.5,-0.03,0.0,1.0,0.04,0.0,131.44,892.58,0.0,0.44,0.03,0.0,-0.02,-0.0,0.0,1.0,0.03,0.0,131.85,892.59,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.03,0.0,132.23,892.6,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.03,0.0
234.56,799.4,0.0,0.04,-0.25,0.0,0.04,-0.25,0.0,-0.15,0.99,0.0,234.71,799.15,0.0,0.04,-0.25,0.0,0.04,-0.25,0.0,-0.13,0.99,0.0,220.67,879.17,0.0,-1.09,7.05,0.0,0.61,-3.94,0.0,0.07,1.0,0.0,145.21,890.9,0.0,2.55,0.16,0.0,2.48,0.24,0.0,0.99,0.11,0.0,219.96,884.8,0.0,-0.7,4.55,0.0,0.28,-1.8,0.0,0.06,1.0,0.0,157.92,891.89,0.0,1.99,0.23,0.0,1.93,0.26,0.0,0.99,0.13,0.0,219.01,888.81,0.0,-0.71,4.63,0.0,-0.37,2.37,0.0,0.05,1.0,0.0,201.31,894.36,0.0,-9.83,-1.31,0.0,-1.44,-0.19,0.0,-1.0,0.06,0.0,212.88,899.3,0.0,0.67,0.11,0.0,0.7,0.11,0.0,0.99,0.16,0.0,178.06,891.27,0.0,-13.36,-1.78,0.0,-1.99,-0.26,0.0,-1.0,0.08,0.0
786.44,406.25,0.0,13.63,4.75,0.0,0.34,0.12,0.0,0.95,0.31,0.0,800.07,410.98,0.0,13.64,4.76,0.0,0.45,0.16,0.0,0.95,0.31,0.0,813.7,415.71,0.0,13.61,4.75,0.0,0.45,0.16,0.0,0.95,0.31,0.0,265.32,48.46,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.1,0.99,0.0,265.42,49.86,0.0,-0.25,2.41,0.0,-0.21,2.05,0.0,-0.09,1.0,0.0,268.13,53.81,0.0,-0.48,4.61,0.0,-0.25,2.4,0.0,-0.09,1.0,0.0,270.72,59.95,0.0,-0.81,6.67,0.0,-0.21,1.76,0.0,-0.11,0.99,0.0,269.58,67.76,0.0,-1.33,8.73,0.0,-0.34,2.21,0.0,-0.14,0.99,0.0,267.92,77.55,0.0,-1.65,10.67,0.0,-0.34,2.17,0.0,-0.14,0.99,0.0,265.98,89.45,0.0,-2.28,12.74,0.0,-0.27,1.51,0.0,-0.16,0.99,0.0
    ....
```

Now I'm trying to load the dataset in R studio

```
    library(data.table)
    library(parallel)
    library(cluster)
    library(clusterCrit)
    library(TSrepr)
    library(OpenML)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(grid)
    library(animation)
    library(gganimate)
    library(av)
    library(reshape2)
    library(transformr)
    library(rJava)
    library(farff)
    library(RWeka)
    library(foreign)
    
    #data=readARFF("/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF")
#data=read.arff(system.file("arff","/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF",package="RWeka"))
#data<-read.arff(file=" /Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF",fill=TRUE)
n <-122
#data<-read.table("/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF", 
#          header = FALSE, sep = ",", comment.char = "@")
data<-read.table( /Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF, 
           header = FALSE, sep = ",", skip = n)
    data <- data.matrix(data$data)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I appreciate it if anyone can help me for the problem. In the comment, I added what I tried to load data and again received the same error.

Comment: try [`farff::readARFF`](https://github.com/mlr-org/farff)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it shows me the following error: Error: 'read.arff' is not an exported object from 'namespace:farff'

Comment: That's because there is no function in that package called `read.arff`. You need to use  `readARFF`, as @missuse suggested.

Comment: thanks, do u mean data=readARFF(file=".../city-info.ARFF"). it shows me the error: could not find function "readARFF"

Comment: @ttina first install package `farff` then load it `library(farff)` then use the function `readARFF` to open your file. Be sure to read the help for the function first `?readARFF`.

Comment: That message means you must first load the package with `library(farff)` or use a qualified form like in @missuse 1st comment above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did like what you said, However I get an error Parse with reader=readr : /Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF
header: 0.007000; preproc: 0.004000; data: 0.029000; postproc: 0.000000; total: 0.040000
 0sError in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Answer (score 1):

Here are several approaches.  For the first two we note that if we ignore the lines before the first data line then it is just an ordinary data file with no header and comma separated fields.

In all these alternatives we use File defined in the first alternative.

Also, if there are any lines in the file with a fewer number of fields than the others then add `fill=TRUE`.

```
# 1 - ignore @ lines by defining @ as the comment character
File <- "/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF"
read.table(File, header = FALSE, sep = ",", comment.char = "@")

# 2 - an alternative if that does not work is
n <- # set this to number of lines before the first data line
read.table(File, header = FALSE, sep = ",", skip = n)
```

Another thing to try is to use read.arff in the foreign package. That package comes with R and does not have to be installed, only loaded using a library statement.  Start a fresh instance of R without all those library statements and run this after defining File:

```
# 3 - this alternative uses read.arff in foreign package
library(foreign)
read.arff(File)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried all of the above suggestions, however I get the same error. Also I added fill= TRUE  in the argument data<-read.arff(file="/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF",fill=TRUE) but it shows me unused argument (fill = TRUE)

Comment: Just when I use data=readARFF("/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF",fill=TRUE) it shows me the following error: Parse with reader=readr : /Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF
Error in read_delim(tmp.file, delim = ",", col_names = FALSE, col_types = col.types,  : 
  unused argument (fill = TRUE)

Comment: fill only applies to `read.table`.  Are you sure you did all this with a fresh instance of R omitting all those library statements in the question?  foreign uses `read.arff`, not `readARFF`.  If everything fails there is likely something wrong with your file.  Delete the last half and see if any of these work.  If not delete the last half again and try to narrow it down to the bad lines.  Also try `count.fields(File, sep = ",")` and see if any of the field counts are wrong.  Also try varioius large values to skip to see if you can skip over the bad part.

Comment: I tried to keep just 1 line data and deleted the rest in the file and still received the error. Also I added this line to my code count.fields("/Users/harirrazzazi/Downloads/VeReMi-Dataset/GTruth/sumo-output-w/London_5months_5066ID.ARFF", sep = ",") and still with this line of code I get the same error Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Comment: Did you try this on a fresh instance of R without any packages loaded?

Comment: Also note that every one of the answers I posted works for me if I create a file with what is shown in the question so there is some question of reproducibility here.

Comment: Do you mean I have to choose session> Restart R? Yes I did and still got the error

Comment: Yes. There seems to be something wrong specific to your installation since I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just ran the following code.     library(RWeka)
data<-read.arff("/Users/har/GTruth/sumo-output-w/city-info.ARFF") this didn't give me an error but after I add the following line,  data <- data.matrix(data$data)   it shows me the same error.

Comment: When I just write data it produces correctly my data in the console.